# Send parent's reference to child component

Tags: angular

I want to send a parent's reference to a child component, hopefully with something like this:

```
<parent-component #parentReference>
  <child-component Xdirective="parentReference">
    anything this component contain but with a reference to parent.
  </child-componet>
</parent-component>
```

Comment: What specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? How would the parent reference be used inside the child component?

Comment: By default in angular, when you pass an object as input, it is passed by reference and when you pass any primitive type, it is passed by value. But why do you need that? what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a reference to a component using the `exportAs` declaration of a component.

```
@Component({
    ....
    exportAs: 'parentReference'
})
export class ParentComponent {}

@Component({...})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input()
    public parent: ParentComponet;
}
```

You have to assign the exported value `parentReference` to a template value, and then pass that into an input parameter.

```
<parent-component #ref="parentReference">
   <child-component [parent]="ref">
      anything this component contain but with a reference to parent.
   </child-componet>
</parent-component>
```

You can also inject a parent component via the constructor, but this will not work if the child is inside a `<ng-content>` block.

```
@Component({...})
export class ParentComponent {}

@Component({...})
export class ChildComponent {
    constructor(parent: ParentComponent) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to use `exportAs`? Couldn't you simply set the `#ref` template variable by itself? I thought that `exportAs` was mainly useful for directives and for components with an attribute selector.

Comment: @cgTag, it's better use `@Host` and forget the `@Input`, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

If your child has an unique parent (always is the the child of the same class of Component) you can use @Optional() @Host(), see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tr5l13?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

```
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit  {
  @Input() name: string;
  constructor(@Optional() @Host() private parent:AppComponent){
  }
  ngOnInit()
  {
    console.log(this.parent.anotherVariable)
  }
}
```

But, if you can resolve your problem using @Input ot @Output it's better solution